# First elements in sublists

Tags: list-manipulation

Given

```
t1 = {{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, {15, 16}, 7}}, {11, 12, 13, 14}};
```

I try to get `First` elements from sublists which would yield

```
{1,5,15,11}
```

How to use `First`, `Take` or `#1` for this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If preserving the "order" of extracted elements matters, you can use

```
ClearAll[fa, fb]

fa = Cases[ReplaceRepeated[{a : Except[_List], b__} :> {{a}, b}]@#, {x_} :>  x, All] &;
fb = Cases[MapAll[# /. {a : Except[_List], b__} :> {{a}, b} &, #], {x_} :> x, All] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
t1 = {{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, {15, 16}, 7}}, {11, 12, 13, 14}}; 
t2 = {{a, 2, 3, 4}, {b, 6, {c, 8, {{d, 8, 9}, {e, 3, 3, 2}}, {f, 5, 7}}}};(*from cvgmt's answer*)
t3 = {{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, {15, {16, {17, {18}}}}, 7}}, {11, 12, 13, 14}};

fa /@ {t1, t2, t3}
```

> ```
>   {{1, 5, 15, 11}, 
>    {a, b, c, d, e, f},
>    {1, 5, 15, 16, 17, 18, 11}}
> ```

```
fb /@ {t1, t2, t3}
```

> ```
>   {{1, 5, 15, 11}, 
>    {a, b, c, d, e, f},
>    {1, 5, 15, 16, 17, 18, 11}}
> ```

Answer (score 7):

If integers are what counts as first elements:

```
Cases[t1, List[a_Integer, ___] :> a, All]
(* {1, 15, 5, 11} *)
```

Comment: Or `Cases[t1, List[a_ /; NumberQ[a] , ___] :> a, All]` for arbitrary numbers

Comment: Great! But I don't understand the function of "All" here. It makes sense for me in Part but not here.

Comment: @user57467 You can extract `{5, 6, {15, 16}, 7}}` from your `t1` with `Part` using 2 index arguments, whereas you need 3 index arguments to extract `{15, 16}` with `Part`. The 3rd argument of `Cases` specify the depth(s) at which to look for the pattern, and to obtain `{1, 5, 15, 11}` you need to consider all depths.

Answer (score 7):

```
Cases[First /@ Cases[t1, _List, Infinity], Except[_List]]
```

> ```
> {1, 15, 5, 11}
> ```

Answer (score 6):

Another way suitable for all list.

```
t2 = {{a, 2, 3, 4}, {b, 
    6, {c, 8, {{d, 8, 9}, {e, 3, 3, 2}}, {f, 5, 7}}}};
Cases [t2, {x_ /; ListQ[x] == False, ___}, {0, Infinity}]
First /@ %
```

The two outputs are

```
{{a, 2, 3, 4}, {d, 8, 9}, {e, 3, 3, 2}, {f, 5, 7}, {c, 
  8, {{d, 8, 9}, {e, 3, 3, 2}}, {f, 5, 7}}, {b, 
  6, {c, 8, {{d, 8, 9}, {e, 3, 3, 2}}, {f, 5, 7}}}}
```

```
{a, d, e, f, c, b}
```

Comment: Thanks! You helped me to understand the difference between Infinity and All

Comment: But I still dont get the meaning of ListQ[x] == False, ___ Can you explain, please!

Comment: @user57467   since we want to look for  the form  `{ x, ___}` instead of  `{{ ___ }}` or `{  List[ ___ ]  }`  , so we need to exclusion `{ List[ ___ ]  }`, that is the form `{x_ /; ListQ[x] == False, ___}`